# Can't Install dart on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: flutter, dart, macos-catalina

I want to install dart language with brew in my MacBook Pro. My MacBook OS details is - ***macOS Catalina 10.15.4***. But It's throw an error. Could you please some one help me out ?

I followed the below steps from here - https://dart.dev/get-dart

```
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart
```

Then I got this error message from terminal

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing dart from dart-lang/dart
==> Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/2.8.2/sdk/dartsdk-macos-x64-release.zip
-=O=-       ###
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443 
Error: Failed to download resource "dart"
Download failed: https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/2.8.2/sdk/dartsdk-macos-x64-release.zip
```

Comment: you don't need dart separately for flutter, just use the path of dart inside flutter

Comment: But I need to install Dart for practicing dart locally.

Comment: using jetbrains ide?

Comment: @Doc No, I am using VS Code.

Comment: dart-sdk can be found at `/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/`. add to your path and it should work

Comment: @Doc It is blank for me. Initially it will be blank. Once setup complete then it will filled with downloaded dart packages. I can't install Flutter or Dart due to cURL, openssl and LibreSSL issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using a VPN? As storage.googleapis site is down in Bangladesh for over a month.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Yes, google storage site is down for Bangladesh. I installed it using VPN.

Comment: this one helped me https://programmerah.com/mac-installation-dart-error-curl-35-libresssl-ssl_-connect-ssl_-error_-syscall-in-connection-to-storage-googleapis-co-11933/

Comment: @lokesh-coder Thank you man, your instructions also worked for me